# Elasticsearch - Autocomplete performance improvements

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index with about 2M records that is currently really hurting the CPU, when autocomplete queries are sent.

I was looking at creating a new index just for autocomplete and seeding just the names instead of the having the entire object (which is quite large) in the index.

In theory, would this speed up the autocomplete and stop hurting the CPU so much?

Comment: Maybe you can add your mapping, 2 example documents, and your actual queries? It's hard to discuss this in an abstract way if you have a specific problem